Integração de um Interpretador Portugol dentro de um projeto simples IDE
inserir a descrição da imagem aquiEu sou estudantes, e estou em projeto do  governo pra desenvolver um conversor de linguagem. Eu crie uma interface web simples usando html,css,js e php bem básico, mas preciso fazer com que na area designada que separei, possa ser editável pra colocar código em portugol e o terminal que fiz ao abrir, execute esse código portugol.
Como posso pensar em fazer essa integração? colocar dentro do meu projeto simples
para que um código editável dentro da web em portugol seja executado
Preciso que rode no navegador e não no servidor.
Que o codigo seja editavel e o resultado seja mostrado no terminal do exemplo

IDE é uma coisa, interpretador de linguagem é outra. PHP geralmente é back-end, html, css, js é front, no navegador. A pergunta está bastante ambigua em vários pontos, mas o problema que parece que deveria ser o foco é "como executar portugol em web?", estou correto? Se for o caso, defina, quer executar do lado do servidor ou no navegador do usuário?

Outra coisa que deve-se levar em conta num projeto desses é a segurança. Executar scripts aleatórios, tanto em cliente quanto em servidores pode levar uma invasão que certeira do ambiente de execução. Talvez para vocês seja bom estudar virtualização e containers.

quero executar no navegador do usuario, e seria integrar um interpretador no meu projeto, que até entao o foco é fazer rodar na minha pagina parecidi como portugol studio web e sites semelhantes
